# Progress bar Angular 2

Tags: javascript, ionic, angular

Preciso implementar uma progress estilo a da imagem, preciso criar na mesma estrutura, aberta em baixo e com estas informações. Irá ser utilizado em um app Ionic, alguém sabe alguma lib ou como fazer um? Abraço!!

[image: Progress Bar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que esse aqui pode ajudar.

http://crisbeto.github.io/angular-svg-round-progressbar/

https://github.com/crisbeto/angular-svg-round-progressbar